# How to declare/define an associative array properly in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array, error-reporting

I wrote a program to define an associative array titled `$aFilter` and tried to print it but I'm not able to. I tried two ways to achieve this but couldn't succeed. Following are the two ways I tried.

**Way 1:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$aFilter = Array
        (
            ['pages'] => 1,
            ['photo'] => 1,
            ['link'] => 1,
            ['event'] => 1,
            ['friend'] => 1,
            ['user_status'] => 1,
            ['poll'] => 1,
            ['quiz'] => 1,
            ['market'] => 1,
            ['apps'] => 1
        )
        print_r($aFilter);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

**Way 2:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$aFilter = Array
        (
            ['pages'] => 1
            ['photo'] => 1
            ['link'] => 1
            ['event'] => 1
            ['friend'] => 1
            ['user_status'] => 1
            ['poll'] => 1
            ['quiz'] => 1
            ['market'] => 1
            ['apps'] => 1
        )
        print_r($aFilter);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

After executing both of the above codes I'm getting blank white screen. No any error or warning. Why so happens? How can I get errors and warnings displayed on my webpage without making any change to php.ini file settings?

Can someone please correct the mistake I'm making and help me?

Comment: you already appended ;now remove brackets of keys(these -> `[]`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot an `;` after defining the array.
And also don't use [] when defining an array. [More info on array's.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

```
$aFilter = Array(
            'pages' => 1,
            'photo' => 1,
            'link' => 1,
            'event' => 1,
            'friend' => 1,
            'user_status' => 1,
            'poll' => 1,
            'quiz' => 1,
            'market' => 1,
            'apps' => 1
        );
        print_r($aFilter);
```

[print_r()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) displays information about a variable in a way that's readable by humans.
It is not the code you need to write.

Comment: I tried this code after appending semi-colon but still I'm getting blank array. Why so?<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$aFilter = Array
        (
            ['pages'] => 1,
            ['photo'] => 1,
            ['link'] => 1,
            ['event'] => 1,
            ['friend'] => 1,
            ['user_status'] => 1,
            ['poll'] => 1,
            ['quiz'] => 1,
            ['market'] => 1,
            ['apps'] => 1
        );
        print_r($aFilter);
?>

</body>
</html>

Comment: @PHPNut Don't use [] when defining an array just quote your keys see my edited answer

Answer (score 3):

Both ways are missing the `;` after the array definition and Way 2 is missing `,`s after each array element. Also, both ways should use `'elName' => 'elValue',` instead of `['elName'] => 'elValue',`

Answer (score 3):

The problem are:-

1. Forgot an ; after defining the array.
2. When you hard-coded value you need to put indexes without brackets.

So write in this way:-

```
$aFilter = Array(
            'pages' => 1,
            'photo' => 1,
            'link' => 1,
            'event' => 1,
            'friend' => 1,
            'user_status' => 1,
            'poll' => 1,
            'quiz' => 1,
            'market' => 1,
            'apps' => 1
        );
        print_r($aFilter);
```